# Trying to store interface when preg_match_all is executed using php

Tags: php, preg-match-all, mib, oid, snmpwalk

I would like to store the interface name only. So in this case, I would like to store Interface900. Below is my code. Can't seem to figure out how to do this.

```
$str = '[TIMETRA-VRTR-MIB::vRtrIfName.22.178] => STRING: "interface900" ';

preg_match_all("!^STRING: \"?(.*?)\"?$!", $str, $matches)) 
print_r($matches);
```

Also tried

```
preg_match_all('(STRING: ")([\w-_]*)', $str, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

IN both cases, it's not printing Interface900. I'm not too good with regex or php. Can someone help me please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your RegEx is incorrect, it should be:

```
STRING: \"?(.*?)\"? $
STRING: \"?              // Match the string 'STRING: ' followed by an optional double quote
           (.*?)         // Non-greedy capture anything until the next character in the pattern
                \"? $    // Match an optional double quote followed by a space and the end of the string {$}
```

**Example**

```
preg_match_all("/STRING: \"?(.*?)\"? $/", $str, $matches);
print_r($matches);

/* Output:
    Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [0] => STRING: "interface900" 
            )
    
        [1] => Array
            (
                [0] => interface900
            )
    
    )
*/

preg_match("/STRING: \"?(.*?)\"? $/", $str, $matches);
print_r($matches);

/* Output:
    Array
    (
        [0] => STRING: "interface900" 
        [1] => interface900
    )
*/
```

**Why your RegEx failed**

```
^STRING: \"?(.*?)\"?$
^                        // Matches the start of the string {DOESN'T MATCH}
 STRING: \"?             // Match the string 'STRING: ' followed by an optional double quote
            (.*?)        // Non-greedy capture anything until the next character in the pattern
                 \"?$    // Match an optional double quote followed immediately by the end of the string {DOESN'T MATCH}
```

Answer (score 0):

The second pattern has the value in capturing group 2. Note that `\w` also matches an underscore.

A bit more precise pattern without a capturing group could be asserting the closing `"` and repeat the character class at least 1+ more times to prevent an empty match.

```
\bSTRING:\h+"\K[\w-]+(?=")
```

**Explanation**

- `\bSTRING:` Match `STRING:`
- `\h+"` Match 1+ horizontal whitespace chars and `"`
- `\K[\w-]+` Reset the match buffer, then match 1+ times either a word character or `-`
- `(?=")` Positive lookahead, assert `"` directly to the right

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/wnEg8v/1) | [Php demo](https://3v4l.org/h5J0j)

```
$re = '/\bSTRING:\h+"\K[\w-]+(?=")/';
$str = '[TIMETRA-VRTR-MIB::vRtrIfName.22.178] => STRING: "interface900" ';

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
print_r ($matches[0]);
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [0] => interface900
)
```

---

Matching the whole string, you might also take the leading square brackets into account, and match 1+ word chars followed by optionally repeating a `-` and 1+ word chars to prevent matching only hyphens.

You might also use the capturing group for example:

```
\[[^][]+\]\h+=>\h+STRING:\h+"(\w+(?:-\w+)*)"
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/GTvl5d/1) | [php demo](https://3v4l.org/2PEdC)